# Undefined symbols for QCompare

Tags: qt, qtestlib

When building a test with QTestLib, I get an "undefined symbols" error for a `qCompare` function:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZN5QTest8qCompareIimEEbRKT_RKT0_PKcS8_S8_i", referenced from:
      __ZN15MyTestClass22myTestFunctionEv in MyTestClass.o
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can decipher the mangled symbol by passing it through `c++filt` in a shell command:

```
echo __ZN5QTest8qCompareIimEEbRKT_RKT0_PKcS8_S8_i | c++filt
```

... which prints a C++ function signature like this:

```
bool QTest::qCompare<int, unsigned long>(int const&, unsigned long const&, char const*, char const*, char const*, int)
```

The two arguments to the `QCOMPARE` macro — i.e., the two template arguments to the `qCompare` function — must have exactly the same type. You get an error, for example, if one is an `int` and the other is a `size_t`.

Comment: ...so the solution is to static_cast the types or, in case ofliterals, use the correct type by using "0ul" etc.

Comment: FYI: It seems that this is no longer an issue with more recent versions of Qt (on Ubuntu 18.04 the error is still seen whereas on Ubuntu 20.04 it is gone).